# Select Link after fetching label in front of it

Tags: html, selenium

I am writing a selenium java code and at a particular webpage i want to select a link from a group of links where each link has an emebeded text within a table. How can i select particular link at this situtation. for eg.

```
run title--text 1
run title--text 2
run title--text 3
```

how can select specific run link for a specific title text? the text is not a label rather it is just simple text on the webpage.

i am using the following code:

```
verify.text("text 1");
```

it will only verify the presence of text, it wont go towards the link as link of every execution is named RUN. so it will identify the corresponding run link? The HTML code for the above is:

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>TEST</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <div align="center"><table class="module" width="630">

<tr>
<th class="banner" width="70">ACTION</th>
<th class="banner" width="560">REPORT TEMPLATE</th>
</tr>





 <tr>

 <td class="modulenav" width="70">
 <table class="innermodule" width="100%">



    <tr><td class="moduleNav"><a class="listingLink" 
        href="www.abc.com/">Run</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td class="moduleNav"><a class="listingLink" 
        href="www.zxc.com">UnShare</a></td></tr>

    </table>
    </td>

    <td>
    <table class="innerModule" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td class="label" width="70">Title</td>
         <td width="490"><span class="listingHead">Incident Performance by Priority</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Label" width="70">Description</td>
      <td class="listing"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Label" width="70">Owner</td>
      <td class="listing"> Software Engineer&nbsp; Tel: </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Label" width="70">Shared With</td>
      <td class="listing">

      Software Engineer &nbsp;Tel: <br>


      </td>
      </tr>


       <tr>
      <td class="label">Report Type</td>
         <td class="listing">Performance by Priority</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
     </td>
     </tr>
    <tr><td class="tableRuleNavy" colspan="2"></td></tr>

    <tr>

   <td class="modulenav" width="70">
  <table class="innermodule" width="100%">



    <tr><td class="moduleNav"><a class="listingLink" 
        href="www.abc.com">Run</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td class="moduleNav"><a class="listingLink" 
        href="www.cxd.com">UnShare</a></td></tr>

  </table>
 </td>



 <td>
  <table class="innerModule" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td class="label" width="70">Title</td>
         <td width="490"><span class="listingHead">Incident Trend Analysis Report</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Label" width="70">Description</td>
      <td class="listing"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Label" width="70">Owner</td>
      <td class="listing">Software Engineer&nbsp; Tel: </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Label" width="70">Shared With</td>
      <td class="listing">




       Software Engineer &nbsp;Tel: <br>


      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td class="label">Report Type</td>
         <td class="listing">Trend Analysis</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
<tr><td class="tableRuleNavy" colspan="2"></td></tr>

<tr>

<td class="modulenav" width="70">
  <table class="innermodule" width="100%">



    <tr><td class="moduleNav"><a class="listingLink" 
        href="www.sdfds.com">Run</a></td></tr>



    <tr><td class="moduleNav"><a class="listingLink" 
        href="www.asdg.com">UnShare</a></td></tr>


  </table>
</DIV>
</td>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of web elements and iterate over them. 
This is not tested
E.g.

```
List<WebElement> we = findElements(By.cssSelector("tr a"));

Iterator itor = we.iterator()
While(itor.hasNext()) {
    WebElement we = itor.next();
    if (we.getText().equals("your visible      text")) {
        we.click // click link
    }
}
```

Comment: Bcar, like i said all the visible text for the links is RUN and i want  to select the RUN after getting the title value from the user and click on that particular "RUN" link